# Finding spectrum of $M_f.$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, spectral-theory

> Let $f \in C(\Bbb R)$ be a bounded continuous function on $\Bbb R.$ Consider the multiplication operator $M_f : L^2 (\Bbb R) \longrightarrow L^2 (\Bbb R)$ defined by $M_f (g) = fg, g \in L^2 (\Bbb R).$ What will be $\sigma (M_f),$ the spectrum of the operator $M_f\ $?

By definition, $$\sigma (M_f) = \left \{\lambda \in \Bbb C\ |\ (M_f - \lambda I) \notin GL \left (L^2(\Bbb R) \right ) \right \}.$$ Now let $\lambda \in \rho (M_f),$ the resolvent of the operator $M_f.$ That implies $(M_f - \lambda I) \in GL \left (L^2 (\Bbb R) \right ).$ When can it happen? If $\lambda \notin \text {ran}\ f$ then clearly it will be the case because then $M_{(f - \lambda)^{-1}}$ will serve as the inverse of $(M_f - \lambda I).$ What about the converse? If $(M_f - \lambda I) \in GL \left (L^2 ( \Bbb R ) \right )$ can we always say that $\lambda \notin \text {ran}\ f\ $? I think it is not necessarily the case for otherwise $\sigma (M_f) = \left (\rho (M_f) \right )^c = \text {ran}\ f,$ which is not necessarily closed. So I guess that $\sigma (M_f) = \overline {\text {ran}\ f}.$ But how to prove it rigorously?

Any help in this regard will be warmly appreciated. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The spectrum is the closure of the range $R$ of $f$.

If $\lambda \notin \overline R$ then the equation $(M_f-\lambda I)g=h$ has  a unique solution $g=\frac h {f-\lambda}$ for every $h \in L^{2}(\mathbb R)$ and $\|g\|_2 \leq M\|h\|_2$ where $M=\frac  1 {\inf \{|f(x)-\lambda|: 0 \leq x \leq 1\}}$. Hence $\lambda \notin \sigma (M_f)$.

Now suppose $M_f-\lambda I$ has a bounded inverse. Then $h (\frac 1 {f-\lambda}) \in L^{2}$ for every $h \in L^{2}$. By a well known result in Functional Analysis (which has appered many times on this site) this implies that $\frac  1{f-\lambda}$ is essentially bounded. By continuity this implies that $\lambda \notin \overline R$

Comment: How can you say that $(M_f - \lambda I) g = 1$ will imply that $g = \frac {1} {f - f(x_0)}$ almost eveywhere? For that the set $\{x \in \Bbb R\ |\ f(x) = f(x_0) \}$ has to have measure zero. Right? But that might not be the case always. For example, we could have taken constant function $f \equiv f(x_0)$ on $\Bbb R.$

Comment: @Anacardium My answer was wrong. I have corrected the answer. The spectrum is not the closure of the range of $f$.

Comment: So my guess was wrong. Isn't it? Because I can't see why $$\left \{\lambda \in \Bbb C\ \bigg |\ \displaystyle {\int \left \lvert \frac {1} {f - \lambda} \right \rvert\ d\mu = \infty} \right \} = \overline {\text {ran}\ f}.$$

Comment: @Anacardium Yes, we cannot say anything about finiteness of $\int |\frac 1 {f(x)-f(x_0)}|^{2}$ in general.

Comment: Not to be a spoilsport but when you appeal to Hölder's inequality, you prove that $g$ has a well-defined $1$-norm, not that $g\in L^2$.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Thank you for pointing out. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: @Anacardium Your guess was correct after all!. The above comment by WoolierThanThou  made me work through the proof again.